# Generating a randomized path in Python from

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, path-finding

## Goal

I need to create a function that inputs a flattened uniform 2D-grid, the current location index and q, amount of steps to take. It should then output a randomized path with length q,  an array of the next indexes for the flattened grid.

```
def findPath(flat_grid,current_location,q=5):


    """Find the next gridpoints to traverse in q steps.

    Parameters
    ----------
    flat_grid : numpy array
        Flattened grid. If len(flat_grid) = N points, the grid is n x n = N.
    current_location : int
        Index of current location in flattened grid
    q : int
        The amount of steps to take in the traverse

    Returns
    -------
    Array
        An array of the next q gridpoints to traverse in the grid
    """

    #Formula 2d to 1d: index = index_X + n* index_Y 
    #Formula 1d to 2d: x = index % n, y = floor(index / n)
    
    
    return output
```

### Restrictions

The path has to be connected in 2D, has to be chosen randomly, and also needs to handle edge cases.

Example:

If we have a 25 x 25 grid, a flattened version is row 1 + row 2 + row 3 etc. If we start at location 0,0 (index 0 in the flattened grid), a valid output with q=10 would be
[1, 2, 27, 28, 54,55,56,81,106,131].

I would appreciate tips on how to make this algorithm work as I intend! I am open to various ideas, e.g. first selecting the end-node with length q from the current location, and then using a shortest path algorithm, or simply for each step, randomly selecting which direction to go.

PS: This is not for homework, but for a personal project I am working on, where I am learning to find a best path for a UAV in a 2d-grid modelled as a GRF with a given mean function and covariance function, where the goal is to use Reinforcement Learning to make the UAV choose the best path based upon the given reward function(currently I am rewarding the UAV moving to higher values in the GRF).

Comment: What are the possible steps? Just orthogonal, or also diagonal? In your example, the result has a length much loger than 3. Is this intentional / am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, q=10 in the example. The possible steps are both orthogonal and diagonal.